# onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent in handler

Tags: android, listview

My goal: Two listviews in one activity. When one listview is scrolled, the other one scroll automatically with 0.15s delay.

My thought is to capture the MotionEvent of scrolling and send it to other listview.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    ArrayList<ListView> mListViews = new ArrayList<ListView>();
        View sourceView;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListViews.add((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lva));
        mListViews.add((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvb));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            adapter.add("#" + i);
        }
        mListViews.get(0).setAdapter(adapter);
        mListViews.get(1).setAdapter(adapter);
        mListViews.get(0).setOnTouchListener(this);
        mListViews.get(1).setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        sourceView = v;
        final MotionEvent ev = event;
//      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
                for(ListView lv : mListViews){
                    if(!lv.equals(sourceView))
                        lv.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }
//          }
//      }, 150);
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

Result:

If I comment the handler.postDelayed part, two listview can scroll in sync(with no delay).
But if I uncomment the handler.postDelayed part, the other listview has no reponse.

> I expect  to see the other listview with 0.15s delay.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    adapter.add("#" + i);
}
final ListView lv0 = new ListView(this);
lv0.setAdapter(adapter);
ll.addView(lv0, params);
final ListView lv1 = new ListView(this);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
ll.addView(lv1, params);
setContentView(ll);

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MotionEvent event = (MotionEvent) msg.obj;
        lv0.onTouchEvent(event);
        event.recycle();
    }
};
OnTouchListener l = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(0, MotionEvent.obtain(event));
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1500);
        return false;
    }
};
lv1.setOnTouchListener(l);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The other listview can scroll with a delay(It is 150. not 1500) with your example. but if I scroll up and down real quick. The scroll offsets of two listview will be different when I stop scrolling. Also, May you explain why my code in updated question is not working?

Comment: in lv.onTouchEvent(ev); instead of ev pass a copy of ev: MotionEvent.obtain(ev)

Comment: I print the objects of a copy of ev and MotionEvent.obtain(ev). I cant see the different. Still not understand it clearly. Does ev invalid itself within 0.15s? So when I try to use the copy of ev, it is no longer working?

Comment: does it work when you use MotionEvent.obtain(ev) or not?

Comment: Yes. It works. But I dont understand why MotionEvent.obtain(ev) but not final MotionEvent event = ev.

Comment: try to Log.d ev.hashCode() and youll understand why